# How do you delete a TFS build using the Build API?

Tags: tfsbuild

The TFS Build API is pathetically underdocumented on MSDN.  How do I delete an existing build definition through the API?

(I want to delete one before I make a replacement with updated settings...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be working for me (found via trial and error) so far.

```
try
{
    var def = buildServer.GetBuildDefinition(
        teamProject, buildDefinition.Name, QueryOptions.Definitions);
    buildServer.DeleteBuilds(def.QueryBuilds());
    def.Delete();
}
catch (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildDefinitionNotFoundException)
{
    // didn't exist, so do nothing..
}
```

Comment: I 've upvoted your answer, since you 're probably right that it does provide with info that isn't available elsewhere. Yet I must stress you need to be careful with that Axe: You really don't want to invoke the above on a build definition you need!

Comment: @pantelif: :) No doubt.  Of course, if I'm successful at this particular venture, I won't care that much if they're accidentally deleted, as I'll be generating them all automatically.  We're currently maintaining 40 or so - clients x deployment sites x branches ... it's miserable.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can specify a particular build (drop folder only)

```
var bs = tpc.GetService<IBuildServer>();
var bSpec = bs.CreateBuildDetailSpec(projectName, buildDefinitionName);
bSpec.QueryOptions = QueryOptions.None;
bSpec.InformationTypes = null;
bSpec.QueryDeletedOption = QueryDeletedOption.ExcludeDeleted;

var targetBuild = bs.QueryBuilds(bSpec).Builds.Where(b => b.Uri == build.Uri).ToArray();
bs.DeleteBuilds(targetBuild, DeleteOptions.DropLocation);
```